# Best practice for storing passwords that need to be reused?

Tags: c#, mysql, security, encryption, hash

We have an automation platform that needs to store service account passwords in a database.

These passwords are used in a variety of different cases but generally need to be reversed into their original plain text form in order to be functional.

The service accounts are all compartmentalized to do very specific things - however, I'm uncomfortable leaving them in the database in plain text.

What is the best method/technique for storing passwords in a database when they need to be reversible?

For specific recommendations the platform is using **C#, .Net MVC**, and MySQL (MariaDB).

My immediate plan would be to store them after signing them with a non-exportable private key held in the local key store on the application server. Then reversing the encryption method when reading them out of the database.

If this is the technique I should be using are there particular methods I should be aware of?

Thank you for any help or information.

**[Edited To Re-Open and remove the "Opinion Based" classification. Microsoft had particular documentation for this exact use case. I can't add an answer or mark as answered until it is but my solution is as follows:]**

The recommendation from the Microsoft Engineering team was to use the [Machine Key class and methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey.protect(v=vs.110).aspx#See%20Also).

Utilizing a machine key set and generated via IIS and a uniquely generated "purposes" string provided to the Protect method I can securely encrypt and decrypt a column and leave it secure while at rest.

In MariaDB (MySQL) you'll need to use a column of tinyblob to store the byte array.

I don't believe this is an opinion based answer since this is the defacto way to do it with the technologies specified in the question.

[image: IIS Machine Key]

Comment: You should encrypt them symmetrically with a key derived from the users password.  This is the only way to keep the decryption key off of your server.

Comment: You shouldn't ever know the key to decrypt your users passwords.. Is there a reason you can't just use the salt + hash method?

Comment: @BrandonMiller the OP talks about service accounts and automation, meaning his app needs to be able to log in using the stored credentials.

Comment: You already mention key store. And that is effectively what you are trying to build. Why not use that same key store to keep your passwords?

Comment: _"...What is the best practice..."_ - this is primarily **opinion-based**.  OP and upvoters should perhaps take a refresher of [ask] and authors of the answers below perhaps shouldn't feed the pigeons.  _[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)_ and _[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)_

Answer (score 2):

Usually, to perform activities on behalf of a user with another service provider, you would use a scheme like OAuth2.

In this case, I assume this is not available or provided.

The issue with encrypting passwords as compared to hashing them is that encryption is a two-way function, it can be reversed, and this is in itself a security issue, since anyone with the key can decrypt the password.  The issue then becomes *how do I keep the key safe*?

The answer is simple: **Don't keep the key anywhere on your system.**

Use your own users password to derive an encryption key, and then use this to encrypt their other passwords that you are storing for use with other services.  When you need these passwords, the user must provide their "master" password to authorize the action

This has the benefit that if your database was compromised, no passwords would be recoverable.  Additionally, if your front facing server was compromised, the only attack vector would be to modify the behaviour and wait for users to attempt to login.

From a more technical point of view, do the following:

- When a user creates an account with you, derive a key from their password (PBKDF2 is a good choice).  Let's call this `k1`.
- Randomly generate another symmetric key, let's call this `k2`.
- Encrypt all external passwords for other services with `k2`, which you can get each time by deriving `k1` again and then decrypting.
- If the user wants to change their account password, simply decrypt `k2` with the old `k1`, derive a new key from their new password, and encrypt `k2` again with the new key.

You should really avoid storing user passwords in a form that is reversible.  But if you **absolutely have to**, the above is a good approach that keeps things relatively secure.

Comment: This is a good scheme as long as the user can is available to authenticate for each password use. The catch is that usage may be needed in the absence of the user. In that case the passwords need to be encrypted and the encryption key saved using an HSM or on a server that is not available on the Internet, rate limited and alarmed and the encryption/decryption done the HSM/server..